# What is a proper way to write an Airflow Sensor on top of Redshift Spectrum with option to skip partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, airflow, etl, aws-glue

I have a hourly Airflow ETL that rely on some data in Redshift Spectrum (with Glue as a metastore). I want this ETL to wait for a full data be available, that's why I have sql sensor that waits for data of a next hour to be ingested.

But this approach stops working in case some discrete data, for example, when I have natural empty window for several hours or days.

What is the best approach to skip some ETL run?